# Adding fields to custom User model with Cookiecutter Django

Tags: python, django, cookiecutter-django

I am having difficulty creating custom User fields using the [Cookiecutter Django](https://github.com/pydanny/cookiecutter-django) framework. I have changed the cookiecutter template significantly - removing `django-allauth` but a lot of the structure remains the same.

If I wanted to add another field to the User model (for example, "department" - the users are employees), where would I add it?

I figured I could add a `department` variable to `users/models.py` but it doesn't seem to work. When I login to the `admin` site, I don't see a `department` field when I add a user. Similarly, I don't see a `name` field in the admin site - I only see First Name, Last Name, and Email Address.

```
# users/models.py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals, absolute_import

from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.db import models
from django.utils.encoding import python_2_unicode_compatible


@python_2_unicode_compatible
class User(AbstractUser):

    # First Name and Last Name do not cover name patterns
    # around the globe.
    name = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=255)
    department = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=5)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('users:detail', kwargs={'username': self.username})
```

The admin file:

```
# users/admin.py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals

from django import forms
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin as AuthUserAdmin
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserChangeForm, UserCreationForm

from .models import User


class MyUserChangeForm(UserChangeForm):
    class Meta(UserChangeForm.Meta):
        model = User


class MyUserCreationForm(UserCreationForm):

    error_message = UserCreationForm.error_messages.update({
        'duplicate_username': 'This username has already been taken.'
    })

    class Meta(UserCreationForm.Meta):
        model = User

    def clean_username(self):
        username = self.cleaned_data["username"]
        try:
            User.objects.get(username=username)
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return username
        raise forms.ValidationError(self.error_messages['duplicate_username'])


@admin.register(User)
class UserAdmin(AuthUserAdmin):
    form = MyUserChangeForm
    add_form = MyUserCreationForm
```

Comment: @pydanny - When you create a new tag, you should take the time to write a good tag wiki and excerpt for it as well. Without that, reviewers see a new tag with no guidance and one question... aka a tag that provides no value.

Comment: @Mogsdad Thanks for the advice, I will do that today. :)

Comment: @Mogsdad How does it look?

Comment: Honest feedback: it sounds like a testimonial, not a tag wiki. Someone who's only vaguely aware of it would not have a clear idea of how to use the tag to categorize a question. There are plenty of worse examples, of course.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the [fieldsets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.fieldsets) attribute:

```
@admin.register(User)
class UserAdmin(AuthUserAdmin):
    form = MyUserChangeForm
    add_form = MyUserCreationForm
    fieldsets = (
        ('', {'fields': ('department',)}),
    ) + AuthUserAdmin.fieldsets
    list_display = ('username', 'department', 'is_superuser')
    search_fields = ['username', 'department']
```

You don't need to set the attributes `list_display` and `search_fields` to display your `department` field. But I left them in the sample since they are very handy when it comes to `Django` admin customization.

ModelAdmin.[list_display](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_display):

> Set list_display to control which fields are displayed on the change
>   list page of the admin.

ModelAdmin.[search_fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.search_fields):

> Set search_fields to enable a search box on the admin change list
>   page. This should be set to a list of field names that will be
>   searched whenever somebody submits a search query in that text box.